# MM in datetime picker not working propertly

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set a custom format for DateTimePicker. My desired result is `Wednesday/May 05/2019` and I'm using `dddd/MMM MM/yyyy` as the CustomFormat.

[image]

In Visual Studio design form I see:

[image]

But when I run it and change the date from May 5th to May 31st:

[image]

The `dddd` (day of week) gets updated correctly, but the date stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may be confusing two different values.

`MM` means the numeric value of the month. As long as your date is within May it will always be **05**.

If your intent is that value be the day of the month, then try `dd`

```
dddd/MMM dd/yyyy
```